# PIWIK Store visits per User ID as well as or instead of per IPs

Tags: matomo

I have piwik to track my website visits. My website has a login page and I would like to do the analysis per userid, not necessarily per IP. Is there a way where piwik can store my user session variable in order me to know exactly which users used a determined page?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is via custom variable.

Basic Code:

`piwikTracker.setCustomVariable(1, "Member", "<?php echo $username;?>", "visit");  piwikTracker.trackPageView();`

visit scope will last for the session

Piwik Docs at:
http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a custom variable, you could use [Piwik's built-in User ID feature](http://piwik.org/docs/user-id/), which also has the added benefit of allowing Piwik to more accurately track uniques.